# container monitoring not enabled by default

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, docker-compose

We would like to monitor docker container metrics parameters like CPU, network, memory etc. we are following https://docs.docker.com/articles/runmetrics/ and found that monitoring metrics is not enabled by default.

```
cat /proc/cgroups 
#subsys_name        hierarchy   num_cgroups enabled
cpuset      1        7         1
cpu         2        7         1
cpuacct     3        7         1
memory      4        7         1
devices     5        7         1
```

As per the documentation we have to enable monitoring by setting up kernel parameters.

> Memory Metrics: memory.stat
>
> Memory metrics are found in the "memory" cgroup. Note that the memory
>   control group adds a little overhead, because it does very
>   fine-grained accounting of the memory usage on your host. Therefore,
>   many distros chose to not enable it by default. Generally, to enable
>   it, all you have to do is to add some kernel command-line parameters:
>   cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1

Anyone knows how to set kernel parameters in docker container (Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml).

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

If your kernel supports `cgroup_enable`, you would add this at boot time, for instance on an Ubuntu machine:

edit `/etc/default/grub`.

update `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory"

then run `sudo update-grub` and `reboot`

If you are using CoreOS, it is already available.

Comment: Can you pls. help for centos ?

Comment: you can take a look in `/boot/grub/grub.conf` and remove any reference to `cgroup_disable=memory` and reboot

Comment: there is no file grub.conf. I installed yum install libcgroup  then service cgroup start and below mentioned is error.                                                      Starting cgconfig service: Error: cannot mount cpuset to /cgroup/cpuset: Operation not permitted
/sbin/cgconfigparser; error loading /etc/cgconfig.conf: Cgroup mounting failed
Failed to parse /etc/cgconfig.conf or /etc/cgconfig.d      [FAILED]